# Socket io in node app on google app engine

Tags: node.js, sockets, google-app-engine

I'd like to run a p2p chat written in node js with socket io on GAE.

My app works locally fine but I get error messages when I run it on the GAE servers related to the socket io I think.

Here are the two relevant script tags of my local `client.html` when running locally:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    // our socket.io code goes here
    var socketio = io.connect("127.0.0.1:1337");
    socketio.on("message_to_client", function (data) {
        to_history(data['message']);
    });

    function send_message() {
        var msg = [document.getElementById("text1").value, user1, uuid];

        socketio.emit("message_to_server", {
            message: msg
        });
    }

</script>
```

I've seen blogs/posts saying that for deployment I need to allow a firewall rule [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401250/how-do-i-deploy-socket-io-to-google-app-engine) (which is in place now). I also tried pointing my deployed app to a static external IP like (after making it static in my google cloud console):

```
var socketio = io.connect('https://104.197.51.XXX')
```

or to point it to the port 65080 specified in my firewall rule (see documentation by google [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/websockets):

```
var socketio = io.connect('https://104.197.51.XXX:65080')
```

None of this works.

I have the html loaded fine and the jQuery part I have and css is also loading just fine. It's just the socket stuff that I seem to be getting wrong. What do I have to change?

If this is of use, here the app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs
vm: true
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, App Engine just doesn't support websockets (yet).  The hack-around you're using is really unreliable for a few reasons:

- it makes a direct connection to the instance, which can go down or be recycled at any time
- Short of magic hackery, there's really no way to get https going down this route.

In short - this is not production ready.  That having been said....

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/websockets

That link will show you a working example and instructions of how to set it up.

Instead of that - I'd suggest using pubnub:
https://www.pubnub.com/docs/nodejs-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk

It has a really nice API, and is going to be way more reliable than anything you can hack together with App Engine (you know, until we fix this).  You can see a few examples that I've done here:

- https://github.com/JustinBeckwith/cloudcats/blob/master/web/public/script.js
- https://github.com/JustinBeckwith/hatspin/blob/master/public/script.js

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. This is really helpful. I'd need my app atm for very small-scale data collection only, so maybe a workaround as outlined in the first link would do. I also found this [other example of websockets in google cloud](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/real-time-gaming-with-node-js-websocket). Why I'm hesitant to switch to pubnub is that my app is build with all controls I want now and I don't know whether a rebuild is worth it.

Comment: Wait what? You show an example of App Engine working with websockets yet you say it still doesn't work? May you please elaborate!

Comment: As I explained it - it will kinda work.  It's just really unreliable, doesn't support https, and will just randomly stop working for a while when your VM goes down.

Comment: Do you have any plans to add websockets support in near future?

Answer (score 1):

I also made the similar chat webapp recently and deployed it on heroku (https://chatterboxxx.herokuapp.com). I also used socket.io for this. I am not sure of GAE, but I don't think you need to specify any IP address in your socket.io js code.
I think you should use

```
var socketio = io();
```

instead of

```
var socketio = io.connect("127.0.0.1:1337");
```

This works well for me.