# Cannot connect to socket.io on Google Cloud App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, websocket, socket.io, gcloud

Currently I am developing a mobile application with ionic 2. Within the application I got chat functionality. The chat functionality is based on Socket io in a NodeJS API. Unfortunality, it is hard to configure the socket io on Google Cloud App Engine. On my local machine it works fine.

Steps I have undertook:

- use port 65080 (and open the firewall port)
- 2 servers (api calls via 8080 and socket io via 65080

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Va2b.png)

Does anybody have a solution? Thank you in advance!

Jelle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, neither socket.io or Websockets currently work on App Engine.  This is something we're actively trying to address:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/how-requests-are-handled#not_supported

Comment: Is there any workaround to get sockets working at Google Cloud? It is possible to connect directly on the IP address, but this situation is not optimal.

Answer (score 1):

This question is almost identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56625908/117638), and there's some new good news:

> GAE support for persistent socket connections arrived in February 2019!
>
> To make this work, you'll need to be using the `flex` environment and modify your `app.yaml` to include `session_affinity`.